# Android Studio Using recently added resources in compose preview in multi-module project

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I started making apps using multiple modules, and ever since I keep having problems with resources. Whenether I add a new resource (string, drawable, font...) and try to use it in a Compose Preview, I get a *Render Issues* error with this message `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: [Resource Name]` even with the new resource being in the same module.

The only way I found to get access to new resources is to restart Android studio, which is really annoying. Does anyone have the same problem ? If so, have you found a way to fix it ?